# Databinding mode Explicit

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've got a listbox that contains a list of objects (lets say addresses)

The list box items source is bound to this observable collection

```
<ListBox x:Name="listDetails"
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

...

Then i've got a text box, this is bound to the name fild of the current object

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxName" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"  />
```

So I expect that the Name property of my current object won't be change unless i explicitly update it..

However it is getting updated... any ideas to why?

Also this is in a window, if i close the window and reopen the window somehow the same selection on the listbox is preserved..

I'd expected once the window was closed then it would forget all about the current selection of it's listbox?

Comment: can you should a little xaml?  It'll be easier to identify your bindings

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to solve it, i added an event to the listgbox

```
private void OnListValueChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox lb = e.Source as ListBox;
            if (lb != null)
            {
                object dc = null;
                if (lb.SelectedIndex != -1)
                    dc = lb.Items[lb.SelectedIndex];

                gridDetails.DataContext = dc;
            }
        }
```

the grid details context was set independently each and every time.